# Pair creation in dictionary only if we have value in a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a python dictionary like this:

```
{'type': 'vlan-tagged',
'aging-timer': parsed_pairs_cli['aging-timer'][0],
'ingress-qos-profile': parsed_pairs_cli['ingress-qos-profile'][0]}
```

The requirement is only if the `parsed_pairs_cli['aging-timer'][0]` has a value, the key value pair should get created else dont have it

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: This could work, not sure it helps: `{'type': 'vlan-tagged', **({'aging-timer': item[0]} if item[0] else {}), **({'ingress-qos-profile': item[1]} if item[1] else {})}`, where `item[0] = parsed_pairs_cli['aging-timer'][0]` and `item[1] = parsed_pairs_cli['ingress-qos-profile'][0]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "`parsed_pairs_cli['aging-timer'][0]` has a value"? Does the key not exist or could it be `None`?

Comment: So write an `if` statement to add the value?

Answer (score 1):

Question not properly defined. Assuming that `parsed_pairs_cli` could lack certain keys.

```py
parsed_pairs_cli = {'aging-timer': [122],
                    #'ingress-qos-profile': [3767]
                    }

dct = {'type': 'vlan-tagged'}
dct.update({key: parsed_pairs_cli[key][0]
            for key in ['aging-timer', 'ingress-qos-profile']
            if key in parsed_pairs_cli})
```

results in

```
{'type': 'vlan-tagged', 'aging-timer': 122}
```